# Powershell script SQL Server AvailabilityGroups

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

I am really new to Powershell and hopefully someone can help me with this error. I have been given the below script that is supposed to  take a list of SQL servers from a text file and lists out the availablity group and the replicas for each.

```
# Import the dbatools and sqlserver modules
Import-Module dbatools
Import-Module sqlserver

# Specify the path to the file containing the list of servers
$serverList = "C:\Path\To\ServerList.txt"

# Read the list of servers from the file
$servers = Get-Content $serverList

# Loop through each server and retrieve availability group information
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    # Get the availability groups on the server
    $groups = Get-DbaAvailabilityGroup -SqlInstance $server

    # Loop through each availability group and retrieve replica information
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        # Get the replicas in the availability group
        $replicas = Get-DbaAvailabilityGroupReplica -AvailabilityGroupName $group.AvailabilityGroupName -SqlInstance $server

        # Output the availability group and replica information
        Write-Output "Availability Group: $($group.AvailabilityGroupName)"
        Write-Output "Replicas:"
        foreach ($replica in $replicas) {
            Write-Output "  - $($replica.ReplicaServerName) ($($replica.ReplicaRole))"
        }
        Write-Output ""
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is on"Get-DbaAvailabilityGroupReplica : The term 'Get-DbaAvailabilityGroupReplica' is not recognized...". I have tried multiple times to reinstall the dbatools and sqlserver module but it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Check for any errors or issues around importing the dbatools module, which is what defines that cmdlet.

Comment: No issues with the install. I even uninstalled and the reran the install with -force.

Comment: If you run `get-command -module dbatools` does it show the function?

Comment: No it does not. I am on latest version (1.1.146).

Comment: I don't use dbatools, but I don't see that function, I do see `Get-DbaAgReplica`

Comment: That helped Sean thanks. I think I got it but I am getting a network error that that is something outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected code. By replacing the cmdlet Get-DbaAvailabilityGroupReplica with Get-DbaAgReplica I was able get the code working. My issue seemed to come from the use of Get-DbaAvailabilityGroupReplica.

```
   # Import the dbatools and sqlserver modules
   Import-Module dbatools
   Import-Module sqlserver
  
   # Specify the path to the file containing the list of servers
   $serverList = "C:\Path\To\ServerList.txt"
  
   # Read the list of servers from the file
   $servers = Get-Content $serverList
  
   # Loop through each server and retrieve availability group information
   foreach ($server in $servers) {
       # Get the availability groups on the server
       $groups = Get-DbaAvailabilityGroup -SqlInstance $server
  
       # Loop through each availability group and retrieve replica information
       foreach ($group in $groups) {
           # Get the replicas in the availability group
           $replicas = Get-DbaAgReplica -AvailabilityGroup $group.AvailabilityGroupName -SqlInstance $server
  
           # Output the availability group and replica information
       Write-Output "Availability Group: $($group.AvailabilityGroupName)"
           Write-Output "Replicas:"
           foreach ($replica in $replicas) {
               Write-Output "  - $($replica.ReplicaServerName) ($($replica.ReplicaRole))"
           }
           Write-Output ""
       }
   }
```

Comment: To make this answer more useful to future readers, you may explain  what was the root cause of the error and highlight what exactly fixes it.